# jQuery .html('<img>') doesn't work in FF and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

This line

```
jq("#description" + tourId).html('<b>Opis: </b>  '+ data);
```

works fine in IE, Firefox and Opera.

But this

```
jq("#images" + tourId).html('<img src=\"img\\gbflag.png\"/>');
```

works only in IE. Firefox and Opera do not show the image. Do you know why?

This is the rest of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
function showImages(tourId) {
    jq(function() {
        jq.post("/TourWebSpring/tourImages.html",
            {tourId: tourId},
        function(data) {
            ...
            ...
            jq("#images" + tourId).html('<img src=\"img\\gbflag.png\"/>');
        });
    });
}

function showDetails(tourId) {
    jq(function() {
        jq.post("/TourWebSpring/tourDetail.html",
            {tourId: tourId},
        function(data) {
            ... 
            jq("#description" + tourId).html('<b>Opis: </b>  '+ data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape anything in the `<img src=\"img\\gbflag.png\"/>` string, since you're using single quotes `'`, it should be  `<img src="img/gbflag.png"/>`

Comment: You are using a backslash in your file path; try using a normal slash instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem may be that you are using the wrong slash after the `img` directory, and I don't believe you need to escape the double quote since you are defining the string with single quotes.  Try:

```
jq("#images" + tourId).html('<img src="img/gbflag.png"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jq("#images" + tourId).html('<img src=\"img\\gbflag.png\"/>');
```

Should be

```
jq("#images" + tourId).html('<img src="img/gbflag.png" />');
```

Answer (score -1):

you dont have to escape, so it should be:

```
jq("#images" + tourId).html('<img src="img\gbflag.png"/>');
```

**UPDATE**

oops, didnt notice you're using backslash.. scott points that out nicely!

Comment: escaping is required when you have to print double quotes inside double quotes

Comment: You don't need to escape the quotes (though it hurts only readability, it's not a syntax error), but you _do_ need to escape a backslash. Though in this case the OP probably needs a forward-slash...

Comment: i think stackoverflow should have a system, where with a downvote, an explaination must be required, so that the OP can figure out why he was downvoted

Comment: I agree with you that unexplained downvotes aren't very helpful, but in this case perhaps whoever downvoted (it wasn't me) felt that my previous comment was explanation enough. Your statement "you don't have to escape" was incorrect when applied to backslashes, and misleading when applied to quotes because you went on to say "it should be..." which implies your suggested change is _necessary_ when it isn't.

Comment: thanks for the clarification nnnnn, actually when I wrote 'you dont have to escape', i did not realize the OP has used a backslash, and i later updated my answer to reflect that. the fact that i didn't notice the backslash, and updated my answer to indicate that, makes me feel kinda odd for the downvote :)